# No se visualiza gráfica 3D

Tags: python, matplotlib

Ya establecí todos los valores para poder hacerla, en la 2D si me sirvió pero acá no se ve por alguna razón. Ya sale la ventana con la "gráfica" pero esta no se ve.[image: No me sale el gráfico 3D de este sistema de ecuaciones. Solo me sale el fondo]

```
    #Los valores de acuerdo a la formula
    Z = (c31 * (a11*X)-(a12*Y))/a13
    Z1 = (c32 - (b21 * X)-(b22 * Y))/b23
    Z2 = (c33 + X-Y)/c33
    
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(21,11))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    
    ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,alpha = 0.5, cmap = cm.Accen,trstride=1, cstride=1)
    ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z1,alpha = 0.5, cmap = cm.Pastel1, trstride=1, cstride=1)
    ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z2,alpha = 0.5, cmap = cm.Paired, trstride=1, cstride=1)
    ax.set_xlabel('X'); ax.set_ylabel('Y');  ax.set_zlabel('Z')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Las variables, c31, a11, a12, a13, etc. son desconocidas, así que cree unos datos... para llenar las varialbes: Z, Z1 y Z2.

***Prueba el siguiente código:***

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LightSource
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d, Axes3D
    
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
    
# Valores para los ejes x=Z, y=Z1, z=Z2
Z = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Z1 = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
Z, Z1 = np.meshgrid(Z, Z1)
R = np.sqrt(Z**2 + Z1**2)
Z2 = np.sin(R)
    
# Creas un degradado del color, para que toda tu figura no se vaya a ver azul
ls = LightSource(270, 45)
rgb = ls.shade(Z2, cmap=cm.gist_earth, vert_exag=0.1, blend_mode='soft')

# Aquí gráficas tus datos
cset = ax.plot_surface(Z, Z1, Z2, rstride=1, cstride=1, facecolors=rgb, linewidth=0, antialiased=False, shade=False)

plt.show()
#plt.close('all')
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]